# Why wont align-items work?

Tags: css, flexbox

HTML

```
.listbox
  .hours
    ul Hours
      li Monday
      li Tuesday
      li Wednesday
      li Thursday
      li Friday
      li Saturday
      li Sunday
```

CSS

```
body
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
```

This should result in the .listbox div centered vertically *and* horizontally, but it doesn't. Here's the pen: http://codepen.io/joshbivens/pen/ByvQwO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the height of the body, otherwise horizontal centering doesn't take into account the entire area that you see.

For codepen, and for responsive design, using `height: 100vh` does the trick. Try this:

```
body
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
  height: 100vh
  ul
    list-style: none
```

http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/xbmRYR

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) for more about view height (vh) and view width (vw), and to learn about browser support.

Comment: I didn't even consider that. CodePens are so simple I forget to style stuff sometimes. Thank you.